# XML parsing to MySQL database with special character

Tags: mysql, encoding, character, sign

I have XML file from my manufacturer where is "diameter sign" ⌀

How can i change diameter sign to something else in PHP? I tried htmlspecialchars() but it is not working. Field in database is empty.

Comment: More details, please.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Show some text - both what it should be and what you see.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

Answer (score 0):

XML file:

```
    <Properties>
...
    <Property ID="3" name="⌀ sacího/výstup. hrdla" value="1""/>
...
    </Properties>
```

I want to change "⌀" diameter symbol in my XML file with PHP, before I will send data to database. I tried htmlspecialchars(), str_replace() and more. Nothing is working. XML file is in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. I did't know that symbol ⌀ is part of norwegian alphabet. It's not a just symbol of diameter but a text character. So it can be lower and uppercase. In my XML is uppercase, but when you copy that (CTRL+C and CTRL+V) to PHP it will be automaticly transfer that symbol to lowercase. Cuz its not a symbol but character htmlspecialchars() is not working a str_replace() is case sensitive.